# Range input that is supposed to update automatically stops updating after being set manually

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a small web app that controls Spotify playback through their API. I have a range slider that updates every second while a song is playing, and it works fine as long as you don't touch it.

But when you change the time slider manually, the slider thumb ceases to move, despite the value updating correctly.

[video of bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0dKY.gif)

The code below:

1. Starts the timer to move the slider every second
2. Adds the event listener to listen for manual changes to the timestamp
3. Calls the Spotify API to seek to the new position,

```
timer = setInverval(updateSlider, 1000);

function updateSlider() {
  let maxDuration = Number(seekSlider.getAttribute("max"));
  let currentPosition = Number(seekSlider.getAttribute("value"));

  console.log(currentPosition);

  if (currentPosition < maxDuration) {
    currentPosition += 1000;
    console.log(currentPosition);
    currentTime.innerHTML = convertTime(seekSlider.getAttribute("value"));
    seekSlider.setAttribute("value", currentPosition);
    const timeProgress =
      100 * (currentPosition / Number(seekSlider.getAttribute("max")));
    seekSlider.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #49cc56 ${timeProgress}%, #444 ${timeProgress}%)`;
  } else {
    clearInterval(timer);
    setTimeout(getContext(updatePopup), 1000);
  }
}

seekSlider.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const time = Number(event.target.value);

  clearTimeout(seekBuffer);

  const timeProgress = 100 * (time / seekSlider.getAttribute("max"));
  seekSlider.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #49cc56 ${timeProgress}%, #444 ${timeProgress}%)`;
  seekSlider.setAttribute("value", time);

  seekBuffer = setTimeout(() => {
    seekTo(time);

    updatePopup();

    console.log("Seeked");
  }, 500);
});

function seekTo(time) {
  try {
    callApi("PUT", SEEK + `?position_ms=${time}`, null);
    console.log(time);
    currentTime.innerHTML = convertTime(time);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

TLDR:
I tried to update the slider thumb every second while a song is playing, and add the ability to seek the track manually. But after seeking manually, the slider thumb stops moving, despite the background and value carrying on.